# How to say "A <noun> for/to <verb noun>"

Tags: grammar

How would I say the following?

Using "for":

1. A cup for drinking.
2. A bed for sleeping.
3. A car for driving.

Using "to":

1. A cup to drink from.
2. A bed to sleep in.
3. A car to drive in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A cup for drinking. 
>   A bed for sleeping. 
>   A car for driving.

These can be translated with the **-ㄴ/는/ㄹ** 'adnominaliser' endings that turn a verb into an adjective that can be placed before a noun.

adding -ㄴ emphasizes that the verb action happened in the past:

> 마신 잔 - the cup (that someone used) for drinking 
>   잔 침대 - the bed (that someone used) for sleeping 
>   운전 한 차 - the car someone drove

You could also add the 았/었 past particles in here for emphasis.

는 means the action is present or 'general':

> 마시는 잔 - A cup being used for drinking.
>   자는 침대 - A bed being used for sleeping. 
>   운전 하는 차 - A car being used for driving

ㄹ means that the action is future or 'potential':

> 마실 잔- A cup to use for drinking.
>   잘 침대 - A bed to use for sleeping. 
>   운전 할 차 - A car to drive

As for these examples:

> A cup to drink from.
>   A bed to sleep in.
>   A car to drive in.

I don't think there's a way to add a preposition as 'neatly' as this in Korean, but you don't have to. Just saying   마시는 잔,  자는 침대, or 운전 하는 차 already implies the obvious location of the action.

If you wanted to emphasise the location of an action, or state a non-obvious location, you could use a separate word for the location and preposition. For example:

> 밑에서 자는 짐대 -  a bed to sleep *under*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I added that last section to see if there was a semantic difference between that group of sentences and the ones above. Thank you!

Comment: @LanceClark yep, vb + -ㄴ/는/ㄹ  is a very flexible construction and I think it covers those examples - but ryanbrainard's point about using (을) 위하다 when saying 'do X for *the sake of*' a person or thing is very relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the situation, `for/to` could be translated a few different ways:

- [`N(을) 위해(서)`](http://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/N_%EC%9C%84%ED%95%B4(%EC%84%9C)): 예) 나는 손님을 위해서 요리를 했어요. (I cooked for the guest.)
- [`AV기 위해(서)`](http://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/%EA%B8%B0_%EC%9C%84%ED%95%B4(%EC%84%9C)): 에) 살을 빼기 위해서 매일 운동을 해요. (I work out everyday in order to lose weight.)
- [`V는 N`](http://hompi.sogang.ac.kr/korean/kkl102/lesson08/gram_note_frame.html): 에) 잠을 자는 침대 (A bed for sleeping)
- [`-용`](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=88913) (with some Sino-Korean words; from 用 meaning "use"): 에) 개인용 (for personal use)

From your examples, the `V는 N` pattern is the closest to what you're looking for, but I wanted to show the others because `for/to` is not something that can be directly and consistently translated, but rather depends on the sentence and has quite different grammatical patterns for different uses. In addition to the link above, I would recommend reading [~는 것 Describing Nouns with Verbs](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit-2-lower-intermediate-korean-grammar/unit-2-lessons-26-33/lesson-26/%20~%EB%8A%94%20%EA%B2%83%20Describing%20Nouns%20with%20Verbs). This pattern is quite a big topic and fundamental to a lot of Korean grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty hard to simplify these extremely broad ranging words "to" and "for" in a non-context-dependent way, but in most of these cases, adding (으)ㄹ to the verb root and placing it before the noun could work.. 마시(다) (to drink) + ㄹ 컵 (cup)= 마실 컵  (a cup to drink from)